# Using input box to Filter KendoGrid

Tags: javascript, filter, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to accomplished to filter my `KendoGrid` using the `input box` but it returns all the data in it. Did I do something wrong in my code? also I'm trying to filter the `KendoGrid` on client side only the data wont sent to `Controller`

Here's my code:

**The input box**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search by Program Name" id="SearchData" name="SearchData">
```

**Function I used to filter**

```
function searchAccount() {

            var SearchProgramData = $("#SearchData").val();
            var ProgramgGrid = $("#grProgram").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
            ProgramgGrid.filter(
                {
                    field: "program_name",
                    operators: "contains",
                    value: "Operating"
                }

            );
            //alert(SearchProgramData);
        }
        $(function () {
            $("#search input").keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    searchAccount();
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already figured it. Just a typo error on `operators: "contains"` it should be `operator: "contains"`